# Office 365 Read only mode

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

Is there anyway to make the Office 365 site collection as read-only mode? Please help me by providing your valuable reply. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For Office 365 you could consider the following options:

**CSOM**

> Prerequisites: [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

In [Tenant Administration API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.online.sharepoint.tenantadministration.aspx) `SiteProperties class` exposes the [SiteProperties.LockState property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.online.sharepoint.tenantadministration.siteproperties.lockstate.aspx) that gets or **sets** the lock state of the site.

```
using (var ctx = GetContext(tenantUrl,username,password)) {
    var tenant = new Tenant(ctx);
    var siteProperties = tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl(siteUrl, true);
    siteProperties.LockState = "NoAccess";
    siteProperties.Update();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

where

```
public static ClientContext GetContext(Uri webUri, string userName, string password)
{
    var securePassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (var ch in password) securePassword.AppendChar(ch);
    return new ClientContext(webUri) { Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword) };
}
```

For more details about lock status follow [Manage the lock status for site collections in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263238(v=office.15).aspx)

**PowerShell**

> Prerequisites: [SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161372.aspx)

You could set the lock state for a site collection using the [Set-SPOSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161394.aspx) command:

```
Set-SPOSite https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/targetsite -LockState [NoAccess|Unlock]
```

---

> Limitation:  for Office 365 it is supported to set `NoAccess|Unlock`
>   values only.

Comment: in my case I am trying to remove readonly flag for my site. Existing value for "LockState" is "ReadOnly". My other site which is not readonly has the value of "Unlock". So I run below code and doesn't give any error but its not setting the value.
                
                siteProperties.LockState = "Unlock";
                siteProperties.Update();
                ctx.Load(siteProperties);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();